# Visualizar json a highchart angular

Tags: angular, angular5, highcharts

una consulta tengo un inconveniente con un grafico mapa con higchart en angular.
tengo ya de una query que me arroja la data pero al momento de colocar al higchart no sale nada

**la data que me arroja de la bd es la siguiente:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "BAZAR FANNY",
        "lat": -11.485713056,
        "lon": -75.271150128
    },
    {
        "name": "FARMACIA FRALIFARMA",
        "lat": -11.558634,
        "lon": -75.1853772
    },
    {
        "name": "ALLPY",
        "lat": -12.082560,
        "lon": -75.204363
    },
    {
        "name": "CHIFA KUAN TANG",
        "lat": -12.4475338,
        "lon": -75.145363772
    }
]




 jsonmap:any;
```

**yo en mi Load de angular ya aqui lo obtengo**

**En mi console si me arroja el dato**

```
load(r){
    this.renderTable05(r,{find:'_05',index:0});
  }

private renderTable05(r,add):void{
    const table=this.report.getTableFind(add.index);
    const report=this.report.getRNameCompleted(add.find);
    const confT= new TableMHService(table);
    confT.results(true,true,false);
    this.config_table[add.index]=confT;
    const params={...confT.getParamsAdd(),...r};
    this.cs.getRegularData(report,params)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe(
    (data)=>{
      let result=data.body['result']; 
     
      this.jsonmap=result.body;
      this.jsonmap=this.jsonmap[0].TCAD;
      console.log(this.jsonmap);
      
    },
    ()=>{
    
    });

    
  }
```

**Aqui le coloco jsonmap que ya obtube en mi load  :   data: this.jsonmap**

```
mapChartOptions: HighchartsMaps.Options = {
   
    chart: {
      map: peruMap,
      proj4: proj4
    },
    title: {
      text: null//"Highcharts Maps - basic demo"
    },
    mapNavigation: {
      enabled: true,
      buttonOptions: {
        alignTo: "spacingBox"
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    colorAxis: {
      min: 0
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Random data",
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: "#BADA55"
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: "{point.name}"
        },
        allAreas: false,
        data:  [
          ['pe-ic', 0],
          ['pe-cs', 1],
          ['pe-uc', 2],
          ['pe-md', 3],
          ['pe-sm', 4],
          ['pe-am', 5],
          ['pe-lo', 6],
          ['pe-ay', 7],
          ['pe-145', 8],
          ['pe-hv', 9],
          ['pe-ju', 10],
          ['pe-lr', 11],
          ['pe-lb', 12],
          ['pe-tu', 13],
          ['pe-ap', 14],
          ['pe-ar', 15],
          ['pe-cl', 16],
          ['pe-mq', 17],
          ['pe-ta', 18],
          ['pe-an', 19],
          ['pe-cj', 20],
          ['pe-hc', 21],
          ['pe-3341', 22],
          ['pe-ll', 23],
          ['pe-pa', 24],
          ['pe-pi', 25]
        ]
      } as Highcharts.SeriesMapOptions,
      {
        // Specify points using lat/lon
        type: "mappoint",
        name: "Corresponsalías",
        marker: {
          radius: 3,
          fillColor: "tomato"
        },
        data: this.jsonmap 
      }
    ]
  };
```

**en mi front tengo asì.**

```
<highcharts-chart id="container" [Highcharts]="HighchartsMaps" [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
        [options]="mapChartOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 465px; display: block;">
      </highcharts-chart>
```

**me guie de aqui:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-map-proj4-pwfaqd

**he intentado esto.**
Como el grafico estaba fuera de mi Private RenderTable05 lo que hice es unir el grafico ya que ese procedimiento ya tenia el json que me arrojaba.
me guie de este enlance:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/highchart-world-map-in-angualr/

```
private renderTable05(r,add):void{
    const table=this.report.getTableFind(add.index);
    const report=this.report.getRNameCompleted(add.find);
    const confT= new TableMHService(table);
    confT.results(true,true,false);
    this.config_table[add.index]=confT;
    const params={...confT.getParamsAdd(),...r};
    this.cs.getRegularData(report,params)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe(
    (data)=>{
      let result=data.body['result']; 
     
      this.jsonmap=result.body;
      this.jsonmap=this.jsonmap[0].TCAD;
      this.jsonmap2=this.jsonmap;
        this.mapChartOptions = {
   
        chart: {
          map: peruMap,
          proj4: proj4
        },
        title: {
          text: null//"Highcharts Maps - basic demo"
        },
        
        mapNavigation: {
          enabled: true,
          buttonOptions: {
            alignTo: "spacingBox"
          }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        colorAxis: {
          min: 0
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "Random data",
            states: {
              hover: {
                color: "#BADA55"
              }
            },
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: "{point.name}"
            },
            allAreas: false,
            data:  [
              ['pe-ic', 0],
              ['pe-cs', 1],
              ['pe-uc', 2],
              ['pe-md', 3],
              ['pe-sm', 4],
              ['pe-am', 5],
              ['pe-lo', 6],
              ['pe-ay', 7],
              ['pe-145', 8],
              ['pe-hv', 9],
              ['pe-ju', 10],
              ['pe-lr', 11],
              ['pe-lb', 12],
              ['pe-tu', 13],
              ['pe-ap', 14],
              ['pe-ar', 15],
              ['pe-cl', 16],
              ['pe-mq', 17],
              ['pe-ta', 18],
              ['pe-an', 19],
              ['pe-cj', 20],
              ['pe-hc', 21],
              ['pe-3341', 22],
              ['pe-ll', 23],
              ['pe-pa', 24],
              ['pe-pi', 25]
            ]
          } as Highcharts.SeriesMapOptions,
          {
            // Specify points using lat/lon
            type: "mappoint",
            name: "Corresponsalías",
            marker: {
              radius: 3,
              fillColor: "tomato"
            },
            data: [ ...(this.mapChartOptions.series[0] as any).data, 
            this.jsonmap2
          ]
          }
        ]
      };
      
      console.log(this.jsonmap);
      console.log(this.jsonmap2);
      
    },
    ()=>{
      
     
    });

    
  }
```

Se tiene que pintar asì.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, HostListener, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { egretAnimations } from 'app/shared/animations/egret-animations';
import { ReportT } from '../../../../core/services/report';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import * as HighchartsMaps from "highcharts/highmaps";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import peruMap from "@highcharts/map-collection/countries/pe/pe-all.geo.json";
import proj4 from "proj4";
import { cra } from '../../../comercial/rda/administracion/cra-map';
import { ComercialService } from '../../../comercial/comercial.service';
import { Subject, ReplaySubject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { SelectService } from '../../../../core/services/select.service';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { TableMHService } from '../../../../core/services/table.service';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class CorresponsalComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
config_table:TableMHService[]=[];
jsonmap:any;
   jsonmap2:[];
load(r){
 this.renderTable05(r,{find:'_05',index:0});
  }
ngOnInit() {
 this.renderTable05({},{find:'_05',index:0});

}

private renderTable05(r,add):void{
    const table=this.report.getTableFind(add.index);
    const report=this.report.getRNameCompleted(add.find);
    const confT= new TableMHService(table);
    confT.results(true,true,false);
    this.config_table[add.index]=confT;
    const params={...confT.getParamsAdd(),...r};
    this.cs.getRegularData(report,params)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe(
    (data)=>{
      let result=data.body['result']; 
     
      this.jsonmap=result.body;
      this.jsonmap=this.jsonmap[0].TCAD;
      this.jsonmap2=this.jsonmap;
        this.mapChartOptions = {
   
        chart: {
          map: peruMap,
          proj4: proj4
        },
        title: {
          text: null//"Highcharts Maps - basic demo"
        },
        
        mapNavigation: {
          enabled: true,
          buttonOptions: {
            alignTo: "spacingBox"
          }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        colorAxis: {
          min: 0
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "Random data",
            states: {
              hover: {
                color: "#BADA55"
              }
            },
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: "{point.name}"
            },
            allAreas: false,
            data:  [
              ['pe-ic', 0],
              ['pe-cs', 1],
              ['pe-uc', 2],
              ['pe-md', 3],
              ['pe-sm', 4],
              ['pe-am', 5],
              ['pe-lo', 6],
              ['pe-ay', 7],
              ['pe-145', 8],
              ['pe-hv', 9],
              ['pe-ju', 10],
              ['pe-lr', 11],
              ['pe-lb', 12],
              ['pe-tu', 13],
              ['pe-ap', 14],
              ['pe-ar', 15],
              ['pe-cl', 16],
              ['pe-mq', 17],
              ['pe-ta', 18],
              ['pe-an', 19],
              ['pe-cj', 20],
              ['pe-hc', 21],
              ['pe-3341', 22],
              ['pe-ll', 23],
              ['pe-pa', 24],
              ['pe-pi', 25]
            ]
          } as Highcharts.SeriesMapOptions,
          {
            // Specify points using lat/lon
            type: "mappoint",
            name: "Corresponsalías",
            marker: {
              radius: 3,
              fillColor: "tomato"
            },
            data: [ ...(this.mapChartOptions.series[0] as any).data, 
            this.jsonmap2
          ]
          }
        ]
      };
      
      console.log(this.jsonmap);
      console.log(this.jsonmap2);
      
    },
    ()=>{
      this.mapChartOptions = {
   
        chart: {
          map: peruMap,
          proj4: proj4
        },
        title: {
          text: null//"Highcharts Maps - basic demo"
        },
        
        mapNavigation: {
          enabled: true,
          buttonOptions: {
            alignTo: "spacingBox"
          }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        colorAxis: {
          min: 0
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "Random data",
            states: {
              hover: {
                color: "#BADA55"
              }
            },
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: "{point.name}"
            },
            allAreas: false,
            data:  [
              ['pe-ic', 0],
              ['pe-cs', 1],
              ['pe-uc', 2],
              ['pe-md', 3],
              ['pe-sm', 4],
              ['pe-am', 5],
              ['pe-lo', 6],
              ['pe-ay', 7],
              ['pe-145', 8],
              ['pe-hv', 9],
              ['pe-ju', 10],
              ['pe-lr', 11],
              ['pe-lb', 12],
              ['pe-tu', 13],
              ['pe-ap', 14],
              ['pe-ar', 15],
              ['pe-cl', 16],
              ['pe-mq', 17],
              ['pe-ta', 18],
              ['pe-an', 19],
              ['pe-cj', 20],
              ['pe-hc', 21],
              ['pe-3341', 22],
              ['pe-ll', 23],
              ['pe-pa', 24],
              ['pe-pi', 25]
            ]
          } as Highcharts.SeriesMapOptions,
          {
            // Specify points using lat/lon
            type: "mappoint",
            name: "Corresponsalías",
            marker: {
              radius: 3,
              fillColor: "tomato"
            },
            data: [ ...(this.mapChartOptions.series[0] as any).data, 
            this.jsonmap2
          ]
          }
        ]
      };
      
    });

    
  }

mapChartOptions: HighchartsMaps.Options = {
   
    chart: {
      map: peruMap,
      proj4: proj4
    },
    title: {
      text: null//"Highcharts Maps - basic demo"
    },
    
    mapNavigation: {
      enabled: true,
      buttonOptions: {
        alignTo: "spacingBox"
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    colorAxis: {
      min: 0
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Random data",
        states: {
          hover: {
            color: "#BADA55"
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: "{point.name}"
        },
        allAreas: false,
        data:  [
          ['pe-ic', 0],
          ['pe-cs', 1],
          ['pe-uc', 2],
          ['pe-md', 3],
          ['pe-sm', 4],
          ['pe-am', 5],
          ['pe-lo', 6],
          ['pe-ay', 7],
          ['pe-145', 8],
          ['pe-hv', 9],
          ['pe-ju', 10],
          ['pe-lr', 11],
          ['pe-lb', 12],
          ['pe-tu', 13],
          ['pe-ap', 14],
          ['pe-ar', 15],
          ['pe-cl', 16],
          ['pe-mq', 17],
          ['pe-ta', 18],
          ['pe-an', 19],
          ['pe-cj', 20],
          ['pe-hc', 21],
          ['pe-3341', 22],
          ['pe-ll', 23],
          ['pe-pa', 24],
          ['pe-pi', 25]
        ]
      } as Highcharts.SeriesMapOptions,
      {
       
        type: "mappoint",
        name: "Corresponsalías",
        marker: {
          radius: 3,
          fillColor: "tomato"
        }
        ,
        data: this.jsonmap2
      }
    ]
  };


}
```

**corresponsal.component.html:**

```
 <highcharts-chart id="container" [Highcharts]="HighchartsMaps" [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
    [options]="mapChartOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 465px; display: block;">
  </highcharts-chart>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes, primero la explicación, luego el código:

La renderización de componentes que tienen propiedades pasa cuando ya tienen lo necesario para que se muestre, en caso tengas datos que falten, una forma de hacer funcionar la renderización es tener una variable que sirva de "flag", es decir, una variable del tipo boolean con valor inicial en `false`, de modo que en el componente.html se tiene `*ngIf="estaListoParaMostrarse"` y una vez que se hayan recibido los datos completos para mostrar el contenido del componente, pues, se coloca la variable como verdadera, dando como resultado el renderizado propiamente dicho.

Dicho, todo esto, vamos por el código, considerando solo lo que está mostrado en la pregunta bajo la edición (https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/447245/11) :

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highmaps";
import worldMap from "@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json";
import peruMap from "@highcharts/map-collection/countries/pe/pe-all.geo.json";
import proj4 from "proj4";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = "mapChart";
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {};
  mostrarGrafico: boolean = false;
  listaDeDatosQueVienenDelServidorEnAlgunMomento;

  GenerandoNuevaRenderizada(): void {
    // Lo siguiente seguro viene un arreglo de la API:
    this.listaDeDatosQueVienenDelServidorEnAlgunMomento = [
      {
        name: "ABC SAC",
        lat: -12,
        lon: -76
      },
      {
        name: "ABC1 SAC",
        lat: -12,
        lon: -74
      },
      {
        name: "ABC2 SAC",
        lat: -10,
        lon: -74
      },
      {
        name: "ABC3 SAC",
        lat: -9,
        lon: -74
      },
      {
        name: "ABC4 SAC",
        lat: -9,
        lon: -75
      },
      {
        name: "ABC5 SAC",
        lat: -11,
        lon: -71
      }
    ];

    this.chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        map: peruMap,
        proj4: proj4
      },
      title: {
        text: "Highcharts Maps - basic demo"
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: `Jugando con Highchart mediante coordenadas lat/lon.<br>
      Source <a href='https://fredyfx.com' target="_blank"> https://fredyfx.com </a> `
      },
      mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
          alignTo: "spacingBox"
        }
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: true
      },
      colorAxis: {
        min: 0
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Random data",
          states: {
            hover: {
              color: "#BADA55"
            }
          },
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: "{point.name}"
          },
          allAreas: false,
          data: [
            ["pe-ic", 0],
            ["pe-cs", 1],
            ["pe-uc", 2],
            ["pe-md", 3],
            ["pe-sm", 4],
            ["pe-am", 5],
            ["pe-lo", 6],
            ["pe-ay", 7],
            ["pe-145", 8],
            ["pe-hv", 9],
            ["pe-ju", 10],
            ["pe-lr", 11],
            ["pe-lb", 12],
            ["pe-tu", 13],
            ["pe-ap", 14],
            ["pe-ar", 15],
            ["pe-cl", 16],
            ["pe-mq", 17],
            ["pe-ta", 18],
            ["pe-an", 19],
            ["pe-cj", 20],
            ["pe-hc", 21],
            ["pe-3341", 22],
            ["pe-ll", 23],
            ["pe-pa", 24],
            ["pe-pi", 25]
          ]
        } as Highcharts.SeriesMapOptions,
        {
          // Specify points using lat/lon
          type: "mappoint",
          name: "Canada cities",
          marker: {
            radius: 5,
            fillColor: "tomato"
          },
          data: this.listaDeDatosQueVienenDelServidorEnAlgunMomento
        }
      ]
    };
    this.mostrarGrafico = true;
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<highcharts-chart *ngIf="mostrarGrafico" id="container" [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
  [options]="chartOptions" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">
</highcharts-chart>

<button (click)="GenerandoNuevaRenderizada()">Cargar datos</button>
```

Aquí está el ejemplo funcionando:

https://highcharts-angular-map-proj4-2ccxft.stackblitz.io

Un gif del funcionamiento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por efectos de seguimiento, aquí el package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.5",
    "@highcharts/map-collection": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/proj4": "^2.5.0",
    "highcharts": "^8.2.2",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.9.0",
    "proj4": "^2.6.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
    "@angular/cli": "9.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```